# How do I retrain SSD object detection model for our own dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

i have tried out SSD and YOLO implemetations in tensorflow. Now i want to retrain any of these for my own dataset, say traffic signals. How do i retrain ssd for data apart form pascal voc? can any one help? I am using tensorflow implementation from https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow

Comment: yea just edited the question

Answer (score 2):

Not specific to the implementation, for SSD,

- Since all layers are convolutional, you need to change the number of filters applied in the prediction layers, since (per the paper in p. 4) the output is given as a function of the number of classes you want to predict: i.e., for any prediction layer in the network, for an `m`*`n` feature map, we expect `(c + 4)kmn` outputs/predictions for both classification and localization; `c` is the number of classes you are trying to predict,  `k` is the number of anchors/default boxes used in that feature map, and `m` and `n` are the 2 dimensions of the feature map.
- You may want to change the anchor/default box scales, per the equations given in the paper

Specific to SSD-Tensorflow,

- You need to make sure that the input format matches the interface provided by `tf.contrib.slim`. Currently SSD-Tensorflow only supports Pascal VOC format. I've been having trouble adapting it to accept other datasets. You can see https://github.com/balancap/SDC-Vehicle-Detection/ for an example KITTI interface. The SDC-Vehicle-Detection repo is by the same author as SSD-Tensorflow, though parts of the codebase are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You drop the fully-connected layers from the trained model and add your own fully connected layers that will learn to classify.

Basically, you have something like this:

```
Image -> Conv1 -> Pool1 -> Conv2 -> Pool2 -> ... -> ConvN -> FC1 -> FC2 -> Softmax
```

The first part, the Conv and Pool layers extract image features. The classification part is taking place in the last `FC -> FC -> Softmax`. To train your own classifier based on this trained model, you connect your own fully connected layers to the last Convolutional layer, set the convolutional layers as non-trainable, and then train the network on your dataset.

Say, you want to add 3 fully connected layers and the output layer, it will become something like this:

```
Image -> Conv1 -> Pool1 -> ... -> ConvN - FC1 -> FC2 -> Softmax
                                        \
                                          MyFC1 -> MyFC2 -> MyFC3 -> MySoftmax
```

Your classification output will be `MySoftmax` that will contain the number of classes you have.

Comment: What you are talking is about transfer learning of image classifiers...i am asking about object detectors...