# Is there an easy way to connect a trained image classifier to an object detector?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, classification

An *image classifier* works on an image to detect the presence of a single feature type which could be for example flower, person, rock, dog.

An *object detector* works on an image to detect one or more distinct objects, such as 1 flower, 3 persons, two rocks, and no dogs.  To do this, the object detection method needs to either take an image classifier as a parameter or contain an embedded image classification method.

I retrained an image classifier in TensorFlow by using the [Google recipe](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining).  I also ran an object detector in TensorFlow following the [Google demo notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb).  The Google demo notebook uses a pretained object identifier network which has an embedded image classifier function.

Is there any plug-and-play way to connect an object identifier (focus is on drawing bounding boxes around images) to an object classifier (focus is on differentiating category of a single image), where the identifier and classifier are essentially separate functions, or is my only option to retrain a composite identifier classifier network, as in the [raccoon detector](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9)?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly, do you want to - say detect flowers in an image and subsequently classify it into rose, jasmine, etc?

Comment: No, I want to take an image that has multiple objects such as flowers, kits and people, and add new categories like camel or popsicle stand.  Will revise to make this clear.

Comment: In my opinion you only need to retrain (fine-tune?) the Google Recipe(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) example. However you will need a lot of images of camels or popsicle stands. Once you have an ample dataset of images in 2 different folders of camels and popsicle stands, you can retrain the model. In short the Raccon example is what you want.

Comment: The one (unapproved) answer to a similar question claims that it is a lot more complicated than that (did it get easier in subsequent TF?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493806/how-do-i-retrain-ssd-object-detection-model-for-our-own-dataset